# Printing out dynamically allocated memory in C

Tags: c

I'm a total beginner in programming and got an assignment about dynamically allocated memory. One of the expected outputs was a printf statement where all the entered inputs(integers) are printed in a single line, in a row. I have managed to printf in a for-loop, but thats not enought. How do I printf them in a single code-line? Here's the code:

```
int main()
{ 
    int how_many_integers, count, entered_integers, i, *pSize;

    printf("\nHow many integers are you going to type?\n");
    scanf("%i", &how_many_integers);
    getchar();

    // Allocates memory for the integers.
    pSize = malloc (how_many_integers * sizeof(int));

    // Checks if the integer is 0, and/or reads in all the integers.
    if (how_many_integers == 0)
    {
        printf("No numbers were given.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Please enter your integers.\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < how_many_integers; i++)
    {
        scanf("%i", &entered_integers);
        count++;
        pSize[i] = entered_integers;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < how_many_integers; i++)
    {
        printf("Number: %i\n", *(pSize+i));
    }
    free(pSize);

    printf("Count: %i", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int main{` say what?

Comment: `int main{`? Are you serious? Please post actual code, that's not valid C. Copy-paste from your edited code. If it compiles, it doesn't look like that.

Comment: "\n" adds a new line. When you omit this it prints on the same line

Comment: *print on a single line* Replace the `\n` in printf with a space (and add a `printf("\n");` after the loop)

Comment: I edited the code. And i did omit the "\n" from the loop. But I didn't get expected output, which is eg. Number: 4 6 7 8. Thanks for reaaally quick respons.

Comment: Not related, but you never initialize `count`.

Comment: Print "Number: " before the loop, then just "%i " inside the loop. Note the space after %i. Then print "\n" after the loop if desired. https://ideone.com/PHXcQJ

Comment: Count: I used for just knowing how many integers were entered. But the rest of the adjustments helped me get the expected output, Retired Ninja. Thank you!

Comment: @Jakim unless you initialize `count = 0`, your program is still very wrong.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I now have initialized it like you said. I realised my reply to Michael Walz was very ignorant.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
printf("Numbers:");
for (int i = 0; i < how_many_integers; i++)
{
    printf(" %i", *(pSize+i)); // No \n
}
printf("\n"); // if you want a new line at the end
```

This should result in an output like

`Numbers: 1 2 3 4 5`

And as others mentioned, your `count` variable is never initialized. Initialize it to 0.